# configure object level caching in ehcache

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

Is there any way to configure object or class level caching (each one with different settings) in ehcache? I am using java+spring+mybatis stack.

Also, what would be the ehcache equivalent of following oscache based implementation?

```
public Map<Integer, ProductDetails> getProductDetails(final List<Integer> productIds)
throws Exception{
    Map<Integer, ProductDetails> result = null;

    try{
        //Get from cache.
        result = (Map<Integer, ProductDetails>) cache.getFromCache("AllProductDetails");

        if(result == null){
            throw new NeedsRefreshException("Cache needs a refresh!");
        }
    }
    catch(final NeedsRefreshException nre){
        try{
            result = ProductDetailsDao.getProductDetails("");
            cache.putInCache("AllProductDetails", result);
        }
        catch (final Exception e){
            result = (Map<Integer, ProductDetails>) nre.getCacheContent();
            cache.cancelUpdate("AllProductDetails");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I see that there is no equivalent of com.opensymphony.oscache.base.NeedsRefreshException in ehcache.

What is the recommended way to identify if data for particular object has been expired or if the object is not present in cache at all?

Comment: Why aren't you simply usings Spring Cache Abstraction? That would save you a lot of boilerplate code...

Comment: Thanks for the reply Deinum. How do I do that? Can you please provide some link?

Comment: The Spring Reference guide has a section on [caching](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `getCacheConfiguration` on the EHcache object. You can then modify its [fields](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/2.8.4/net/sf/ehcache/config/CacheConfiguration.html).

Here's some sample code that checks for expiry or missing. Note the use of `getQuiet` to ensure you do not reset the expiry time by looking at it.

```
  public boolean expired(final K key) {
      boolean expired = true;
      // Do a quiet get so we don't change the last access time.
      final Element element = cache.getQuiet(key);
      if (element != null) {
        expired = cache.isExpired(element);
        if (expired) {
          log.trace("Expired because expired.");
        } else {
          expired = element.getObjectValue() == null;
          if (expired) {
            log.trace("Expired because value null.");
          }
        }
      } else {
        log.trace("Expired because not present.");
      }
      return expired;
  }
```